# Confining Substitution to Match Space Using sed?

Tags: sed

Is there a way to substitute only within the match space using sed?

I.e. given the following line, is there a way to substitute only the "." chars that are contained within the matching single quotes and protect the "." chars that are not enclosed by single quotes?

Input:

```
'ECJ-4YF1H10.6Z' ! 'CAP' ! '10.0uF' ! 'TOL' ; MGCDC1008.S1 MGCDC1009.A2
```

Desired result:

```
'ECJ-4YF1H10-6Z' ! 'CAP' ! '10_0uF' ! 'TOL' ; MGCDC1008.S1 MGCDC1009.A2
```

Or is this just a job to which perl or awk might be better suited?

Thanks for your help,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following a try which uses the divide-and-conquer technique:

```
sed "s/\('[^']*'\)/\n&\n/g;s/\(\n'[^.]*\)\.\([^']*Z'\)/\1-\2/g;s/\(\n'[^.]*\)\.\([^']*uF'\)/\1_\2/g;s/\n//g" inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `s/\('[^']*'\)/\n&\n/g` - Add newlines before and after each pair of single quotes with their contents
- `s/\(\n'[^.]*\)\.\([^']*Z'\)/\1-\2/g` - Using a newline and the single quotes to key on, replace the dot with a dash for strings that end in "Z"
- `s/\(\n'[^.]*\)\.\([^']*uF'\)/\1_\2/g` - Using a newline and the single quotes to key on, replace the dot with a dash for strings that end in "uF"
- `s/\n//g` - Remove the newlines added in the first step

You can restrict the command to acting only on certain lines:

```
sed "/foo/{s/\('[^']*'\)/\n&\n/g;s/\(\n'[^.]*\)\.\([^']*Z'\)/\1-\2/g;s/\(\n'[^.]*\)\.\([^']*uF'\)/\1_\2/g;s/\n//g}" inputfile
```

where you would substitute some regex in place of "foo".

Some versions of `sed` like to be spoon fed (instead of semicolons between commands, use `-e`):

```
sed -e "/foo/{s/\('[^']*'\)/\n&\n/g" -e "s/\(\n'[^.]*\)\.\([^']*Z'\)/\1-\2/g" -e "s/\(\n'[^.]*\)\.\([^']*uF'\)/\1_\2/g" -e "s/\n//g}" inputfile
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Dennis!  I completely overlooked the possibility of temporarily modifying the structure of the line to operate on multi-line pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat phoo1234567_sedFix.sed
#! /bin/sed -f
/'[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'/s/'\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\)'/\1_\2/
```

This answers your specific question. If the pattern you need to fix isn't always like the example you provided, they you'll need multiple copies of this line, with reg-expressions modified to match your new change targets.

Note that the cmd is in 2 parts, "/'[0-9][0-9].[0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'/" says, must match lines with this pattern, while the trailing "s/'([0-9][0-9]).([0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])'/\1_\2/", is  the part that does the substitution. You can add a 'g' after the final '/' to make this substitution happen on all instances of this pattern in each line.

The \(\) pairs in match pattern get converted into the numbered buffers on the substitution side of the command (i.e. \1 \2). This is what gives sed power that awk doesn't have.

If your going to do much of this kind of work, I highly recommend O'Rielly's Sed And Awk book. The time spent going thru how sed works will be paid back many times.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, shelter.  I'd been struggling for some time trying to craft a regex that would minimize the greediness of the match and then dennis-williamson clued me in to split the line first.  After that it was a piece of cake ;^)

Answer (score 0):

this is a job most suitable for awk or any language that supports breaking/splitting strings.
IMO, using sed for this task, which is regex based , while doable, is difficult to read and debug, hence not the most appropriate tool for the job. No offense to sed fanatics.

```
awk '{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  {
     if ($i ~ /\047/ ){
        gsub(".","_",$i)
     }
  } 
}1' file
```

The above says for each field (field seperator by default is white space), check to see if there is a single quote, and if there is , substitute the "." to "_". This method is simple and doesn't need complicated regex.

Comment: Thanks for your response, kruimi, I agree with your analysis that awk or perl is a better tool for this kind of manipulation.  @dennis-williamson opened my eyes to trick sed into splitting the line up before substitution and then putting it back together afterwards.

Comment: @phoo1234567, i am sure your eyes are getting tired by now looking at the sed solution :)